# How to store data in session for the next page request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do this:

If the user navigates to the cart page (`CartController`), a `$cart` array gets generated from data from DB (the cart is stored in DB). But some changes are made to the data, such as replacing price with the user's custom price.

If the user clicks Finish order, on the bottom of the cart page, he will submit a form to `OrdersController@store`, which would need to generate the same array `CartController` generates.

To avoid this expensive operation, I want to store the `$cart` array in session, but only for one more request. When the user clicks on Finish order and submits the form to OrdersController@store, the array won't have to be generated again. If he navigates away from the cart page, the array will no longer be held in session storage. And when he visits cart/, it will get generated and stored again.

However, I haven't been able to use flash() or reflash() successfully.

I tried doing reflash() in both controllers but that didn't seem to make a difference. I must have used it incorrectly. I tried `$request->session()->reflash();dd($request)` in store as well as `request()->session()->flash('cart', $cart);$request->session()->reflash()` in CartController.

So I'm trying to hold the data in flash for the next *page request*.

Code of `CartController` and `OrdersController@store`: https://gist.github.com/Shifterovich/e4cf7e23421d495a8cd9a358dd4849d0

Comment: Have you tried `redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Changed')`?

Comment: That's simply a variable that gets passed to the view. The form's controller won't see it. Though I see that I could add a hidden field with JSON interpretation of the cart.

Comment: The `with()` method on a RedirectResponse actually flashes data to the session.

Comment: Keep in mind that the controller method displaying your view is popping the data from the session as well. If you want it to survive until the form is submitted you will have to continuously reflash at every page, at which point it might make more sense to just keep it in the session until submitting.

Comment: > *If you want it to survive until the form is submitted you will have to continuously reflash at every page, at which point it might make more sense to just keep it in the session until submitting.*

I want it to be stored in session only if the user orders immediately after visting the cart page. Otherwise the data is considered obsolete and will not be stored. I'll try ->with('cart', $cart) in CartController and reflash() at the beginning of OrdersController.

Comment: @TravisBritz Reflashing won't work because `_flash['old']` is empty at that point https://pastebin.com/4Nn1yDqM

Comment: Are you reflashing from the controller method that displays the view?

Comment: No, I'm reflashing at the beggining of OrdersController@store. Even if I try to do `request()->session()->flash('cart', $cart);request()->session()->reflash();return view('cart')->with('cart',$cart);` in CartController, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TravisBritz Just look at the pastebin. You can see exactly what I'm doing there.